# Create shortcut using app path

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, nircmd

How can I create a shortcut (perhaps using NirCmd) to `Acrobat.exe` using the path in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe` and parameters `/A "page=10" "file.pdf"`?

Comment: Use `reg query` to get the path, then use `nircmd shortcut`

Comment: Can I combine the two to create a shortcut that looks for the path in the registry rather than hard coding it?

Comment: Yes. Parse the result of the `reg query` and pass it to `nircmd` ...

Comment: I don't suppose you could post a solution, please? (It's beyond me.)

Comment: Done. Answer added. Please let me know of it works (I don't have acrobat installed to test it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I create a shortcut (perhaps using NirCmd) to Acrobat.exe?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem query the registry to get the full path to acrobat
for /f "usebackq tokens=3*" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \Acrobat.exe ^| findstr Default`) do (
  set _acrobat=%%a %%b
  rem create the shortcut
  nircmd shortcut "!_acrobat!" "shortcut_folder" "shortcut_name" /A "page=10" "file.pdf"
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Replace `shortcut_folder` with the name of the folder where you want to create the shortcut
- Replace `shortcut_name` with the name you want to give to the shortcut

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [NirCmd Command Reference - shortcut](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/shortcut.html)

Comment: Thank you, but this appears to create a shortcut with a hardcoded path; is it possible instead always to look for the path in the registry?

Comment: @user2319146 No, that is not possible. Shortcuts don't work that way. If the program is moved somewhere else just delete the shortcut and run the batch file again.

Comment: Perhaps what I need is a batch file that behaves like a shortcut?

Comment: Well you can use the batch file in the answer. Replace `nircmd shortcut "!_acrobat!" "shortcut_folder" "shortcut_name" /A "page=10" "file.pdf"` with `"!_acrobat!" /A "page=10" "file.pdf"`

Comment: Other than that I'm really not clear what your original purpose is with wanting to read the registry every time ...

Comment: Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I tried your suggestion (and added "App Paths\" to the registry path), but nothing appears to happen when I run the batch file (even elevated).

Comment: Like I said I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why are you adding something to the registry path?

Comment: I meant that I corrected the registry path; it was missing "App Paths\". I am trying to create a shortcut that will open a file on more than one machine regardless of where Acrobat is installed.

Comment: That's exactly what my batch file does ... except it doesn't need the `App Paths`. If you really want to add it then you need quotes "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths" because of the space ...

Comment: OK; I thought that might have been missing because it still does not do anything.

Comment: Note there was a mistake in the batch file. There needs to  be a space between `%%a` and `%%b`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Is there any way to close the cmd window after the file has opened (rather than after the file has been closed)?

Comment: Ignore that: "exit", of course.

Answer (score 1):

No third-party software required; you can use PowerShell:

```
# Get the target path from the Registry
$path = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe').'(default)'
# Create the shell and shortcut objects with COM
$wshshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$shortcut = $wshshell.CreateShortcut([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') + '\Acrobat.lnk')
# Configure the shortcut
$shortcut.TargetPath = $path
$shortcut.Arguments = '/A "page=10" "file.pdf"'
# Write the shortcut to disk
$shortcut.Save()
```

The shortcut file appears on the desktop. To change where the shortcut is saved, alter the line with the `CreateShortcut` call.

Shorter one-line version:

```
$w=New-Object -com WScript.Shell;$s=$w.CreateShortcut([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')+'\Acrobat.lnk');$s.TargetPath=(gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe').'(default)';$s.Arguments='/A "page=10" "file.pdf"';$s.Save()
```

To invoke with the command prompt, you just run `powershell` and escape the double quotes appropriately:

```
powershell -command $w=New-Object -com WScript.Shell;$s=$w.CreateShortcut([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')+'\Acrobat.lnk');$s.TargetPath=(gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Acrobat.exe').'(default)';$s.Arguments='/A """page=10""" """file.pdf"""';$s.Save()
```

Comment: Thank you (and for introducing me to PowerShell), but I am looking to create a shortcut that looks for the path in the registry rather than hard coding it.

Comment: @user2319146 The target path *is* retrieved from the Registry; it's the shortcut file's location that's hardcoded. I can change that to be computed from something, if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, please: I want the shortcut file's location always to look for the path in the registry.

Comment: @user2319146 How should it be calculated? Currently, it always goes on the desktop and is called `Acrobat`. I'm afraid I don't understand where you'd like the shortcut to appear, could you clarify that, please?

Comment: On the desktop is fine; I gather I can move it to another location like any other shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click on your desktop and select **New** and then **shortcut**. This will create a standard shortcut.

Comment: As you might have guessed, I am looking to do something a bit more complicated.